# Nuxt.js route URL without dash /

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Is it possible to remove folder dash from URL?

From: `url.com/p/123456` and `url.com/t/123456`

To: `url.com/p123456` and `url.com/t123456`

---

**Folder structure:**

```
/pages
|—/p
|—|—_id.vue
|—/t
|—|—_id.vue
p.vue
t.vue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you put a file inside a folder in the pages folder, it'll generate that `/folderName/` structure because that is its intended behaviour.

To achieve what you want, you simply have to create a slug at the bottom level:

```
/pages
|-_id.vue
p.vue
t.vue
```

From this page, you can access the slug parameter as you would normally.

If you need to distinguish between what was `/p` and what was `/t` files, you can create a computed function that checks a `substring` of the current route and then reacts accordingly.